# Join IEnumerable<aComplexType>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following method in the Data Service Layer.  I got "Unable to create a constant value of type 'appModel.dtoFSR'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context"   exception.  The last parameter assignedFSR is a query result from another application in another app domain in another server.  Thus the entities referred in assignedFSR don't exist in my Entity Framework context.  I don't have access to that database to add those entities to my EF Context. In order to keep the Separation of Concern principle, I don't want to copy into my project the business logic code that returns assignedFSR.  Does anyone know how to overcome this short come?

```
public IPagedList<dtoTask> GetTasks(int pageSize, int pageIndex, bool completed, int? userId, IEnumerable<dtoFSR> assignedFSR)
{
    var tasks = (from t in AppContext.patient_encounter

                 from p in AppContext.patients
                 .Where(x => t.Patient_ID == x.Patient_ID) /* inner join */

                 from u in AppContext.user
                 .Where(x => t.CreatedBy == x.user_ID) /*inner join */

                 from tt in AppContext.encounter_type
                 .Where(x => t.encounter_type.Value == x.encounter_type1).DefaultIfEmpty() /* left outer join */

                 from tr in AppContext.t_encounter_reason
                 .Where(x => t.Reason.Value == x.reasonID).DefaultIfEmpty() /* left outer join */

                 from d in AppContext.doctors
                 .Where(x => p.PCP.Value == x.doctor_ID).DefaultIfEmpty() /* left outer join */

                  from fsr in assignedFSR
            .Where(x => t.ByWhom == x.FacilityServiceRole_ID).DefaultIfEmpty() /*left outer join*/

                 select new dtoTask
                 {
                     Task = t
                     , Patient = p
                     , CreatedBy = u
                     , TaskType = tt
                     , TaskReason = tr
                     , PCP = d
                     , FSR = fsr /* complex type of dtoFSR*/
                 });

    if (completed)
    {
        tasks = tasks.Where(x => x.Task.deleted.Value.Equals(0) && x.Task.Outcome == "Completed")
                .OrderBy(x => x.Task.Scheduled_Date);
    }
    else
    {
        tasks = tasks.Where(x => x.Task.deleted.Value.Equals(0) && x.Task.Outcome.Length == 0)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Task.Scheduled_Date);
    }

    if (userId.HasValue)
        tasks = tasks.Where(x => x.Task.CreatedBy.Equals(userId.Value));

    IPagedList<dtoTask> pagedList = tasks.ToPagedList(pageIndex + 1, pageSize);

    return pagedList;
}
```

Comment: You will have to break up your queries and query the database several times. First get the left part, then join it in memory and with those results get the last part.

Comment: You mean create t, p, u, tt, tr, and d into IEnumerable<> respectively, then join them one by one? Fore example, 
var t = from t in ctx.tasks select t;
var p = from p in ctx.patients select p;

Comment: First make sure you have the list of assignedFSR (for example by calling `ToList`. Then do the same for everything before that call. Join both of them, then execute the third part (also by calling `ToList`) And lastly, when you have all of that you combine them (in memory again). Another way of doing this is trial and error: convert everything into a list and start removing one by one until it fails. But that's cheating ;-)

Comment: Why can't I use IEnumerable<> to join them, instead of casting each to List<>?

Comment: Because `IEnumerable` will defer execution and will try to compile the whole expression to a SQL-statement which is obviously not possible since your object comes from somewhere else. If you use `ToList()` it will compile and execute the expression and load it into memory. From thereon you can do whatever you want. Note: I don't mean casting to List. I mean calling `ToList()` on the IEnumerable<>``

Comment: Thanks.  Could I just use (result from joining the first 5 entities).ToList() then join the assignedFSR.ToList()?

Comment: Yes, as long as all the data is in that db you should be fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41446/discussion-between-user266909-and-kenneth)